# Why is my cURL request not working in XAMPP?

Tags: php, http, curl, xampp, php-curl

curl is enabled in my XAMPP installation.
But my following code returns a blank page:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print $response;
```

Comment: Have you tried this in a browser and then viewed the source to see if there is anything there?

Comment: @NigelRen There is absolutely nothing in the source code. Completely empty.

Comment: try to get curl error by using this code:https://3v4l.org/Kt86v

Comment: @AlivetoDie It gives following error: `string(107) "error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt CApath: none"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `curl_setopt($link, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);` to resolve your issue

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($link, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // to resolve your current error
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
    var_dump($error_msg);exit;
}
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);
```

Note:- The above can come with security issue, so exactly fix this issue try to run below command in your system:

```
/bin/chmod 755 /etc/pki/tls/certs
```

Reference:- [How to fix the Curl Error: error setting certificate verify locations](https://chrisschuld.com/2008/07/how-to-fix-the-curl-error-error-setting-certificate-verify-locations/)

Comment: @Dharman  i know it. I have added a note section regarding it. But thanks for comment.